# Voltage labels too close to circuit element with circuitikz 2.4

Tags: circuitikz

Since upgrading to `circuitikz` 2.4, I noticed that the voltage labels are way too close to the circuit elements.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american voltages,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
   \draw (0,0) to [R=\SI{10}{\ohm},v=$v_r(t)$] (0,3)
               to [C=\SI{10}{F},v=$v_c(t)$] (0,6);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This is what my output looks like with circuitikz 2.4:

[image: labels too close]

Anyone else experience this? Is there an easy fix?

Comment: I am not really familiar with the `circuitikz` package, so I will leave this just as a comment (in case there's a "proper" way of solving the issue). You can add some horizontal space: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american voltages,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to [R=\SI{10}{\ohm},v=\hspace{25pt}$v_r(t)$] (0,3)
             to [C=\SI{10}{F},v=\hspace{25pt}$v_c(t)$] (0,6);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina your solution looks better. You should add it as an answer.

Comment: Related Question: [Spacing circuit element labels from their elements with CircuiTikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48147/spacing-circuit-element-labels-from-their-elements-with-circuitikz/48165#48165)

Answer (score 3):

I am not really familiar with the `circuitikz` package, so maybe there's a more "proper" way of solving the issue. However, you can manually add some horizontal space:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[american voltages,siunitx]{circuitikz} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{circuitikz} 
  \draw (0,0) to [R=\SI{10}{\ohm},v=\hspace{25pt}$v_r(t)$] (0,3) 
    to [C=\SI{10}{F},v=\hspace{25pt}$v_c(t)$] (0,6); 
\end{circuitikz} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo, that doe work, but it is not ideal.   For previous versions of the package, the spacing would be adjusted properly, and the +/- would not be so close to the wire.   I think it's a bug, but am not sure... I'll see if I can figure out where to report this.