# Spacing circuit element labels from their elements with CircuiTikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, labels

I want to draw a resistor with a resistance value showing and a voltage label showing as well. This is content-wise an MWE of everything I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]

    \draw (2,0) to[R=90<\ohm>, v_>=$v_g$] (2,2) ;

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

but when the resistor is vertical, the `v_g` variable is extremely close to the resistor, with the `-` symbol touching the resistor's terminal line, the `+` symbol even crossing the terminal line, and the `v_g` down in the zig zags of the resistor. I just started using `circuitikz` today and am trying to search through the documentation, but does anyone know how to space away the `v_>=$variable_name_here$` part?

Comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill thanks. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Related/Duplicate: [Voltage labels too close to circuit element with circuitikz 2.4](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47781/voltage-labels-too-close-to-circuit-element-with-circuitikz-2-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way, but you can use `label/align=rotate` which produces good results, or add manual spacing (but this does apply to the polarity signs) as shown in the example below.

Here is a comparison of these two options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0) to[R=90<\ohm>, v_>=$v_g$] (0,2)
        node [above] {\tiny\verb|default|};
    \draw (2,0) to[R=90<\ohm>, v_>=$v_g$,label/align=rotate] (2,2)
        node [above] {\tiny\verb|label/align=rotate|};
    \draw (4,0) to[R=90<\ohm>, v_>=$\quad v_g$] (4,2) 
        node [above] {\tiny\verb|\quad|};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436174/18678

Answer (score 3):

This reply may come a bit late, but just in case someone still has an older version of the library (as I happened to have), the problem reported here is fixed in version 0.3.0 of the library.

In its CHANGELOG it states "fixed misalignment of voltage label in vertical bipoles with names", and it fixes that problem, indeed.