# Shift circuitikz component voltage up (or down)

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, circuitikz

Very similar to [Voltage labels too close to circuit element with circuitikz 2.4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47781/voltage-labels-too-close-to-circuit-element-with-circuitikz-2-4) and [Spacing circuit element labels from their elements with CircuiTikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48147/spacing-circuit-element-labels-from-their-elements-with-circuitikz/48165#48165) but with horizontally-oriented components:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, D*, v^=$v_g$] (2,0)
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|default|};
    \draw (0,1) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, D*, v^=$v_g$,label/align=rotate] (2,1)
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|label/align=rotate|};
    \draw (0,2) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, D*, v^=$\quad v_g$] (2,2) 
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|\quad|};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to move the voltage label a little bit further from the component, and don't know how to do it. Things like `\hspace` and `\quad` are horizontal adjustment and don't help vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ah -- I found it: `\raisebox` does the trick:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, D*, v^=$v_g$] (2,0)
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|default|};
    \draw (0,1) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, D*, v^=$v_g$,label/align=rotate] (2,1)
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|label/align=rotate|};
    \draw (0,2) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, D*, v^=\raisebox{1.0ex}{$v_g$}] (2,2) 
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|\raisebox|};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite? Using `\raisebox` with a negative number doesn't work for me.